# Angular 9 & style-loader stopped working after updating from Angular 7

Tags: css, angular

I updated my project from NG7 to NG9.
While i was in NG7 i used to load themes (i have a global styles.scss and inside themes i have different 
 colors to overide), dynamically when my app was served by using the style-loader like this:
`require('style-loader!./../cssThemes/' + environment.MY_CUSTOM_THEME);` (where environment.MY_CUSTOM_THEME is the name of theme.scss) and then the style-loader, load my custom theme on a `<style>` tag inside `<head>` tag. 
Now that i am in NG9 (9.0.4) (typescript 3.7.5), this functionality stopped working.

Does anyone has the same problem? OR maybe has a different solution to provide?
Stackblitz instance:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkc9yt

Comment: Have you check the dev console . Can you post a working issue on the StackBlitz  https://stackblitz.com

Comment: My console is clear, and style-loader seems to work(?), because when i set a wrong filename or path, it throws an error and when set it correctly then stops complaining but it does not insert the styles that i override on my custom theme.... I will try to reproduce that on stackblitz..

Comment: This is an instance of what i would like to implement (and this is how used to work until NG7). Inside app.component.ts there is the style loader in comments, because it throws an error (in my local instance it does not). https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkc9yt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was the problem. When i updated my project through angular cli, the dependencies of style-loader and css-loader was not updated. As a result these dependencies did not work properly (posibbly of the node version , i was in node 7.X and upgraded to 13.X). So i updated them and the problem is now fixed.

Comment: Can you share with us your new dependancy versions?

Comment: Unfortunatelly i left the above project and i have no access to it